How to properly implement createTemplateFromFile for Gmail Addon
Am trying to implement  Gmail addon via app script.  To this effect, I leverage solution found here source
The createTemplate() function as per code below is working fine  as it can output text Hello world
function buildAddOn() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplate('<b>Hello, world!</b>').evaluate().getContent();
  return CardService.newCardBuilder()
  .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('sample'))
  .addSection(CardService.newCardSection().addWidget(CardService.newKeyValue().setContent(html)))
  .build();
}

Here is my issue:
The createTemplateFromFile() is not showing the Sidebar.html Page or its content as per code below.
function buildAddOn() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Sidebar').evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.EMULATED);
  return CardService.newCardBuilder()
  .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('sample xxx')
  .setImageUrl('https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/label_googblue_48dp.png'))
  .addSection(CardService.newCardSection().addWidget(CardService.newKeyValue().setContent(html)))
  .build();
}

Sidebar.html
 <html>
  <body>
My Helloworld form <br/><br/>
    <form >
      <input name = "test" value="test">
      App Form<input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
  </body>


Not sure what you're trying to do but CardService.newKeyValue().setContent(html)) Class keyValue does not have a method setContent()

Here is the solution. According to Ronnie Headen answer from Stackoverflow source
In the overview section of the CardService, It quotes:
“Currently you can only use this service to construct Gmail add-ons.“
So HtmlService is not available in constructing Gmail addon’s currently.
source
The pages were now build using the above aforementioned Card Services and not html pages.
